# p:calendar date informatin is lost

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a

```
<p:calendar id="begin" value="#{addIncidentView.begin}" required="true">
    <f:convertDateTime type="both" pattern="HH:mm" />
</p:calendar>
```

I only want to show the time information in the calendar field. When I now save, the date information will be lost. It wil be 1.1.1970.

Can I somehow preserve the date information and just change the time?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

You can use

```
<p:calendar id="begin" value="#{addIncidentView.begin}" pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true" converter="#{addDateConverter}  />
```

and a Faces Converter

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
public class AddDateConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        String[] split = arg2.split(":");

        Date date = new Date();
        date.setHours(Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
        date.setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));

        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        if (arg2 instanceof Date) {
            Date date = (Date) arg2;
            return date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The converter ist only a **proof of concept**. Use better [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) an a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). But I think the initialized date information is lost. Workaround, save it in a second attribute in the backing bean.

Comment: it has the same effect. date information will be lost

Comment: You shouldn't use date.setHours() and setMinutes() anymore. Use a SimpleDateFormatter and a Calendar instead.